# Add a DependencyProperty to ThreadSeparatedImage class of Meta.Vlc library to follow MVVM model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm working on a Video Player application using C# and WPF.
I have to follow a MVVM model for this WPF project.

I want to use the Meta.Vlc library to display severals RTSP stream in a grid.

So, I add a "ThreadSeparatedImage" object in my VideoPlayControl XAML (view part of the model): 
**VideoPlayerControl.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay.VideoPlayerControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay"
         xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.Wpf"
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:TVSCS_View.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" 
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="controlVideoDisplay"
         DataContext="{Binding ElementName=controlVideoDisplay}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid x:Name="videoPlayerGrid"
              Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <TextBlock x:Name="videoNameText"                   
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                       Text="{Binding Path=VideoStreamName, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
            <vlc:ThreadSeparatedImage x:Name="videoSource"
                                      ThreadImageSource={Binding Path=ImgSource}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Then, I have to implement a DependencyProperty to follow a MVVM model. So I modified Meta.Vlc "ThreadSeparatedImage.cs" class, adding the following code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ThreadImageSourceProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ThreadImageSource", 
                                        typeof(ImageSource),
                                        typeof(ThreadSeparatedImage),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                        new PropertyChangedCallback(ImageSourcePropertyChanged)));

private static void ImageSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ThreadSeparatedImage threadSeparatedImage = obj as ThreadSeparatedImage;

    if (null != threadSeparatedImage)
    {
        threadSeparatedImage.Source = (ImageSource)args.NewValue;
    }
}

public static void SetImageSource(UIElement element, ImageSource imageSource)
{
    element.SetValue(ThreadImageSourceProperty, imageSource);
}

public static ImageSource GetImageSource(UIElement element)
{
    return (ImageSource)element.GetValue(ThreadImageSourceProperty);
 }
```

Finally, I have a view model associated to my "VideoPlayerControl" XAML, with the following properties and methods:

**VideoPlayerViewModel.cs**

```
private ImageSource _imageSource;
public ImageSource ImgSource
{
    get { return _imageSource; }

    set
    {
        if (true == SetProperty(ref _imageSource, value))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImgSource");
        }
    }
}

public void AddVLCPlayer(VlcPlayer mediaPlayer)
{                 
    mediaPlayer.Stop();
    mediaPlayer.LoadMedia(@"rtsp://10.2.92.110:554/profile5/media.smp");
    mediaPlayer.Play();

    ImgSource = mediaPlayer.VideoSource;

    mediaPlayer.VideoSourceChanged += MediaPlayer_VideoSourceChanged;
}

private void MediaPlayer_VideoSourceChanged(object sender, VideoSourceChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ImgSource = e.NewVideoSource;
}
```

"AddVLCPlayer" method could be called at initialization.
With this code, the video stream is neither displayed or updated.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why is `ThreadImageSource` declared as attached property when you use it like a regular dependency property?

Comment: As I'm novice in WPF, it's an error. 
I have changed "RegisterAttached" by "Register" but the behaviour is still the same.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at `threadSeparatedImage.Source = (ImageSource)args.NewValue` to see if it is actually called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Binding like

```
ThreadImageSource="{Binding Path=ImgSource}"
```

in the XAML of your UserControl requires that the `DataContext` of the control is an instance of your view model, i.e. class `VideoPlayerViewModel`.

This is usually achieved somewhere in your MainWindow code, where you might have something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new VideoPlayerViewModel();
}
```

Then the DataContext is inherited by your UserControl somewhere in the MainWindow's XAML tree.

However, this will only work if the UserControl **does not explicitly set its DataContext**, as you do here:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="controlVideoDisplay"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=controlVideoDisplay}">
```

Remove that DataContext assignment. As a general rule, **never** set the `DataContext` of a UserControl explictly, regardless of what they tell you in online tutorials and blog posts.

---

Besides that, you should probably avoid modifying the code of the Vlc `ThreadSeparatedImage` class, and instead create a derived class with your dependency property:

```
public class MyThreadSeparatedImage : ThreadSeparatedImage
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThreadImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ThreadImageSource", 
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(MyThreadSeparatedImage),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ThreadImageSourcePropertyChanged));

    private static void ThreadImageSourcePropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ((ThreadSeparatedImage)obj).Source = (ImageSource)args.NewValue;
    }

    public ImageSource ThreadImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)element.GetValue(ThreadImageSourceProperty); }
        set { element.SetValue(ThreadImageSourceProperty, imageSource); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.
I deleted the DataContext assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I use a classic Image control too.
In XAML file (view part):

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=VideoImageSource}" />
```

In my associated view model (VidePlayerViewModel.cs):

```
private ImageSource _videoImageSource;
public ImageSource VideoImageSource
{
    get { return _videoImageSource; }
    set 
    { 
        if (true == SetProperty(ref _videoImageSource, value))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("VideoImageSource");
        }
    }
}   

public void AddVLCPlayer(string videoStreamPath)
{
    //Create MediaPlayer:
    VlcMediaPlayer = new VlcPlayer(false);
    VlcMediaPlayer.Initialize(Globals.pathLibVlc);

    //Start player
    VlcMediaPlayer.Stop();
    VlcMediaPlayer.LoadMedia(videoStreamPath);
    VlcMediaPlayer.Play();

    //Link VLC player to image source:        
    VideoImageSource = VlcMediaPlayer.VideoSource;
    VlcMediaPlayer.VideoSourceChanged += MediaPlayer_VideoSourceChanged;            
}
```